# Clojure caret as a symbol?

Tags: clojure, caret

So I thought it would be a nice idea to name a function that calculates the exponential `^`, but it seems like the caret actually does something special, as the Clojure REPL generates an error when evaluating `'^`. Googling mostly gave me [this](http://groups.google.com/group/clojure/browse_thread/thread/3c9c65266f3d4203), so I was wondering what the actualy use for the caret in Clojure is.

(Also, would it be possible after all to name a function `^`?)

Answer (score 49, accepted):

`^` is "the meta character" it tells [the reader](http://clojure.org/reader) to add the symbol starting with `^` as metadata to the next symbol (provided it is something that implements IMetas)

```
user=> (def x ^:IamMeta [1 2 3])
#'user/x
user=> x
[1 2 3]
user=> (meta x)
{:tag :IamMeta}
user=>
```

You can learn a lot about how clojure works under the hood by looking at the `meta` of things, for instance functions:

```
user=> (meta foo)                          
{:ns #<Namespace user>, 
 :name foo, :file "NO_SOURCE_PATH", 
 :line 5, :arglists ([s])}
```

this is very often used for [type hints](http://clojure.org/java_interop#Java%20Interop-Type%20Hints)

```
(defn foo [^String s] (.charAt s 1))
```

it is generally a good idea to turn on reflection warnings `(set! *warn-on-reflection* true)` and then add type hints until the warnings go away. without these Clojure will look up the type of the function operands at run-time, which saves you the trouble of fussing with types though at a slight cost.

PS: My next favorite reader character is the "dispatch" character `#`, it is well worth learning about it next :)

PPS: this is different in clojure 1.2.x vs clojure 1.3.x
in Clojure 1.2.1 metadata does not compose when you use the meta-character:

```
user=> (def foo ^:foo ^:bar [1 2 3])
#'user/foo
user=> (meta foo)
{:tag :foo}
```

and in 1.3 it "does the right thing" and also keywords are options instead of "tags":

```
user=> (def foo ^:foo ^:bar [1 2 3])
#'user/foo
user=> (meta foo)
{:foo true, :bar true}
```

Comment: It's not exactly "add the symbol". A symbol is short-cut for a type int. But this also works with strings, eg. `^"B["`. Keywords are translated to options, eg. `^:foo` is turned into `{:foo true}`. And finally you can specify a map itself, eg. `^{:tag String :foo true :bar :baz}`.

Comment: good point kotarak, we should also mention that metadata composes differently in different versions of clojure and I believe that 1.3 starts copmposing chained metadata `^:foo ^:bar [1 3 4]`

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that the answer to your question is, unfortunately, no. In Clojure, you cannot name a function `^`.

I tried the following in the REPL:

```
user=> (println \^)
^
nil
```

This seems to imply that you can escape the carat (`^`) with a backslash. However, if I try to declare a function using `\^` as a name then I get an error message:

```
user=> (defn \^ [n e] (cond (= e 0) 1 :else (* n (\^ n (- e 1)))))
IllegalArgumentException First argument to defn must be a symbol
clojure.core/defn (core.clj:277)
```

The same code works with a regular text name:

```
user=> (defn exp [n e] (cond (= e 0) 1 :else (* n (exp n (- e 1)))))
#'user/exp
user=> (exp 3 3)
27
```

I would be delighted if someone with better Clojure-fu than mine could prove me wrong! :)